# Global UserProfile State for Multiple Dialogs

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I'm building a C# bot using Microsoft bot SDK. I have a main dialog that moves to sequential dialogs throughout a conversation and saves Luis entities to a user profile. At the end, when I return to the main dialog, I need to print out all the entities that are in the User Profile.

```
Main Dialog -> 
Dialog 1 (Save entity to User Profile) -> 
Dialog 2 (Save entity to user Profile) -> , ... , -> 
Main Dialog (Print User Profile Entities)
```

So my user profile looks like this:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public string [] Entity1 { get; set; }
    public string [] Entity2 { get; set; }
}
```

And my current method to update the values in user profile looks like this:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> GetEntity1Async(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var luisResult = await _luisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync<Luis.ConversationBot (stepContext.Context, cancellationToken);
    var userInfo = userProfile(){
        Entity1 = luisResult.Entities.Entity1,
    };

    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"You wrote {userInfo.Entity1}."), cancellationToken);

    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(Dialog2));
}
```

I am stuggling with how to create a 'global' user profile so I can instantiate things in it across the dialogs. I guess printing the entities in the main method at the end will be the same as I am doing it above?

Any help greatly appreciated, new to the bot framework and C#.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with C#...are you using the actual state objects? Bot Framework provides conversation state (across multiple dialogs in a conversation) and user state (multiple dialogs and conversations across sessions, provided you track the userID) that you can use exactly for this purpose. I can provide some more details on implementation but I wanted to check if you were already using that and if it wasn't doing what you wanted.

Comment: I think so ... I have stem added as singletons in the startup class.

Comment: Check this article. I was looking up the C# syntax and it doesn't look like what you are calling userInfo or userProfile is actually part of bot framework state management. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: @UsernameException - Are you still working on this? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney thanks for your reply. I sorted it out by passing the instantiated UserProfile object from main dialog to subsequent dialogs.

Comment: @UsernameException - Would you like to post that as an answer?